# Access to wwwroot denied

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, iis

I'm working on a .NET 7 project using Visual Studio 2022 (Community Edition) and IIS 10. When I publish my project to wwwroot, it works just fine. After I start the WebApplication in my browser (via localhost) and then go back to VS to add some code and then publish it again, I get a *Microsoft.WebTools.Shared.Exceptions.WebToolsException*. Thus it is no longer possible to write to the wwwroot dictionary. Only after I close the browser and restart IIS (which can take quite a while here...), I am again able to publish my project again.
I have to add that all necessary permissions to the wwwroot dictionary are added, even tried to add full permissions on EVERYONE, without having any effect. Maybe I also have to add that I never had this unpleasant behaviour when working with VS 2019 and .NET 4 MVC.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

(Permissions added --> no effect,
Running VS 2022 as admin --> no effect)

[EDIT: Unfourtunately the details of the exception in the output window are in German. They can be translated as e.g. "The file "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyWebApp\DataTables.AspNet.AspNetCore.dll" cannot be deleted. Access to "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyWebApp\DataTables.AspNet.AspNetCore.dll" was denied.  " Also it is mentioned, that another process uses the ressources.]

Comment: Look for a feature that is called something like "hot reload" or "hot update". When IIS starts up the WebApp, the files in that folder are in use and thus cannot be overwritten (which is attempted in a publish run).

Comment: @Fildor This seems only to work when using the IIS bulit-in Visual Studio, but not for the "real" deployment of the Web Application in the C:\inetpub\wwwroot directory (loading ressources from loacalhost without the port specified by VS). Problem is, I need to have "the real stuff".

Comment: Ok, ... assuming you are running the IIS yourself: Have you thought about publishing to a second folder, starting up a second App on that and then redirecting traffic?

Comment: @Fildor In fact, I have - thank you nevertheless, your effort is very much appreciated! I just thought I could circumvent this, because in the "good (not so very much) old days of VS 2019 and .NET 4" I never stumbled across this problem *sigh*. I'll go with your suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, did you try to stop the application on IIS while publishing the app?

Comment: @Baris Of course, but stopping and restarting the application on IIS everytime while developing is a tedious procedure. Especially if you just want to update a single line of code.

Comment: ASP.NET Core is very different, so either you stick to VS/IIS development time support https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/development-time-iis-support?view=aspnetcore-7.0 or you use the approaches listed in the linked thread.